# Application should launch in computer B when user runs url or a command in computer A

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am using combination of node and express js to load my html page. my requirement is , when user enters http://localhost:8080/loadPage in the browser from computer A, the application should launch in computer B. Both the computers are part of same LAN. Please suggest a way.

Answer (score -1):

May I know which Front End Technology you are using to develop your UI. So, that i can suggest something.

For Example:

Method 1:

```
If you are developing your UI in Angular than you can use ng serve --host 192.xxx.xx.xx --port zzzz
```

By this way you can run your angular application and you can also launch in another computer browser using

```
http://192.xxx.xx.xx:zzzz
```

Method 2:

Incase of rendering some Front end application in node.js you can use

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static('./folder_with_html'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/folder_with_html/index.html');
});
```

Thank You

Comment: Hi Kartik, i can directly launch the application as you said. But my question is, suppose when i run some batch file from my machine and application should get open in my colleagues machine. Please correct me if my way of explaining is not understandable.

Comment: I have a doubt? are you going to create a bath file or build file for node.js application? because most of js applications are taken as build file and the running process are same using webpack.

Comment: @Karthik Raja S , if you have questions on the actual question it is better to post it one comment rather that on Anwer.

Comment: Okay Sreehari Sir, I thought my answer will help him but his concern is different.

Comment: Hi Kartik, Yes you are right. my concern or requirement is different. Thank you.